# Writing ObservableCollection to file

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, observablecollection, isolatedstorage, longlistselector

**What I have:**

I currently have this class:

```C#
class Storico
{
    private string rigaStorico;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return rigaStorico; }
        set { rigaStorico = value; }
    }

    public Storico(string storic)
    {
        rigaStorico = storic;
    }       
}
```

This ObservableCollection:

```
ObservableCollection<Storico> rigaStorico = new ObservableCollection<Storico>();
```

And this DataTemplate, located into a LongListSelector:

```XAML
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="●" Margin="0,8,0,0" Foreground="#EE7B00"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" ManipulationStarted="TextBlock_ManipulationStarted" ManipulationCompleted="TextBlock_ManipulationCompleted">
            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="ContextMenu" >
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Name="DeleteItem" Header="Delete Item" Click="DeleteItem_Click"/>
                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

**What I need to do:**

I actually need take all the strings contained into the LongListSelector, that may be like:

```
String1
String2
String3
```

and write them to a file into IsolatedStorage, in inversed order. Something like this:

```
String3
String2
String1
```

Obviously enough, the ItemsSource of the Storico is rigaStorico itself:

```
Storico.ItemsSource = rigaStorico;
```

I hope my goal is clear and I gave all the stuff that's needed to solve it.

Comment: What is missing is the explanation of what you have tried and which is the concrete issue (or, alternatively, the bank data where we can bill you for our contract job).

Comment: I actually have tried playing around with some LINQ, String arrays and such. Once I was told not to post my attempts if they were unsuccesful, as they were adding no value to the question. That's what I am doing now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I solved my issue with the following code:

---

```C#
string[] contenutoStorico = rigaStorico.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();

IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
using (StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("history.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, myIsolatedStorage)))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < contenutoStorico.Length; i++)
    {
        writeFile.WriteLine(contenutoStorico[contenutoStorico.Length-i-1]);                    
    }
    writeFile.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IsolatedStorageFile savegameStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = null;
using (fs = savegameStorage.CreateFile("FILENAME"))
{
    if (fs != null)
    {
        var index = 0;
        foreach(var rigaStor in rigaStorico.Reverse())
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rigaStor.Name);
            fs.Write(bytes, index, bytes.Length);
            index = bytes.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: byte[] bytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(rigaStor.Name); is giving issues. GetBytes reports having different arguments that can be taken.

Comment: @guido1993 Changed it to Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes

Comment: this actually works when I have just one or two elements in my LongListSelector. As I get 3, or more, the app just crashes throwing a "NullReferenceException".

Comment: Check for the null on where it is throwing.

Comment: I posted what worked out for me :) Thanks anyway! I made it more straightforward. At least in my mind this is easier :D

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need them in reverse order, but you could use this [FileStorage](http://codepaste.net/63vh4o) to write the data out.

```
FileStorage.WriteSharedData("MyItems.js", rigaStorico.Reverse());
```

The FileStorage uses json.net under the hood, if you want you could just do:

```
var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
using (var fileStream = storage.CreateFile(fileName))
{
    //Write the data
    using (var isoFileWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rigaStorico.Reverse());
        isoFileWriter.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works, but I am getting results out, all in a line and in this format [{"Name":"str1"},{"Name":"str2"}], when I read them from the file, using this code:
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("history.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
rigaStorico.Insert(0, new Storico(reader.ReadLine())); I'm not sure how I should change your code to fit my needs. I'd prefer keeping mine as that would mean rewriting a large part of my app :)

Comment: Use the FileStorage class and call the ReadSharedData method. `FileStorage.ReadSharedData<ObservableCollection<Storico>>(history.txt");`